# batch scripting - if exist ./sdcard/file.any using adb

Tags: android, batch-file, cmd, adb

I'd like to check whether a file exists on my Android device, and if not - to push it. What is the syntax for doing so using adb on batch?
Something like:

```
if exist ./sdcard/file.any do echo "exists"
else adb push file.any ./sdcard/
```

Comment: Have you tried this: `if exist ./sdcard/file.any do (echo "exists") else (adb push file.any ./sdcard/)` (one-liner)?

Comment: Results in: "else was unexpected at this time"

Comment: You need to put all this in a songle line! try also to put `""` around `./sdcard/file.any`; moreover I recommend `\` as path separator rather than `/`...

Answer (score 1):

Running in a command prompt window `if /?` or `help if` outputs the help pages for internal command [if](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/if).

The command processor is not very tolerant on syntax. An `else` branch is only possible with using parentheses. The true branch must have `(` which must be on same line as command `if` separated with a space from last argument of the condition.

The closing `)` for true branch can be on same line as opening `(` or on a different line.

The keyword `else` must be on same line as closing `)` of the true branch after a space.

If round brackets are used also for the else branch, opening `(` must be on same line as `else` separated with a space from the keyword.

The keyword `do` is completely wrong here as it is a keyword for command **FOR**.

Some of the working variants.

1. Everything on one line with as less spaces as possible (hard to read):

   ```
    if exist "directory\file" (echo exists) else (adb push "file" "directory")
   ```
2. Everything on one line with more spaces for easier reading:

   ```
    if exist "directory\file" ( echo exists ) else ( adb push "file" "directory" )
   ```
3. Condition on first line, true branch on second line, else branch without parentheses on third line:

   ```
    if exist "directory\file" (
        echo exists
    ) else adb push "file" "directory"
   ```
4. Each part of the entire condition on separate lines:

   ```
    if exist "directory\file" (
        echo exists
    ) else (
        adb push "file" "directory"
    )
   ```

There are more variants possible, but they are all horrible to read.

It is best to use second or fourth variant as those two are the best for reading.

I recommend to use always fourth variant if an else branch is used, too.

`.\` at beginning of file name / directory name could be omitted.

And the directory separator on Windows is the backslash character.

**NOTE:** I don't know if `if exist ./sdcard/file.any` or `.\sdcard\file.any` works at all. The question does not contain any information about

- Android version,
- the Android device itself,
- how the device is configured regarding to accessing files and directories on its storage medias – as removable storage(s) making it possible to access the files and directories from Windows command line environment or just via [Media Transfer Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) which is not supported from Windows command line environment,
- in which environment this batch file is running, i.e. what is the current directory, what are the values of the environment variables `PATH` and `PATHEXT`, etc.

So the answer covers only the **IF** syntax mistake, not how to check for existence of a file on any Android device with any Android version connected with whatever device drivers and data storage accessing protocols are used for accessing the device.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kinda old but how about something around the lines of:

```
set cmd="adb shell ls | find /c "theFile" "
FOR /F %%K IN (' !cmd! ') DO SET TEST=%%K
if !TEST! GTR 0 (
    echo the file exists
) else (
    echo the file does not exist
)
```

I am using this for a very similar scenario which works for me. Thought I'd share.

Comment: The idea is good. I don't see any reason for using delayed expansion with the missing line `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` at top. And I think the command __FIND__ is also not needed as it could be enough as first line `set" FileFound="`, as second line `for /F %%I in ('adb shell ls "the file"') do set "FileFound=1"` and as third line `if defined FileFound (`. But I don't have `adb` installed and no mobile device connected to with `adb` and so don't know what `adb shell ls "the file"` outputs on file existing or file missing to verify the command lines as suggested here.