# Asking input with set and if condition in batch

Tags: batch-file

This doesn't work ("incorrect syntax error"):

```
@ECHO OFF

SET /p type="[1] 32bit    [2] 64bit    [3] 32+64bit: "

if %type% == 1
(
  REM Do something here
  REM Do something here
)
```

I thought it was correct, according to the question [How to use if - else structure in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081735/how-to-use-if-else-structure-in-a-batch-file)

**What's wrong?**

Comment: Ever considered to use [`choice`](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) for your task?

Comment: Your example does not follow the same syntax as the example in the link you posted as Magoo has pointed out to you in his answer.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34118487/3074564) with a brief description of __IF__ syntax. Running in a command prompt window `if /?` explains this command and the syntax which must be used as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parenthesis must be on the same line as the `if`