# Using BATCH file to install software (which I have working) and THEN create a shortcut file

Tags: batch-file

Here is what I have so far:

```
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Yawcam\Yawcam.exe" GOTO :eof

ELSE

start \\hazel\software$\YawCam\v6.0\yawcam_install.exe /SP- /VERYSILENT

xcopy "\\hazel\software$\YawCam\Doc Cam.lnk" "C:\users\public\desktop\Doc Cam.lnk" /C /Y

:eof

pause

EXIT
```

Now, it installs properly, but doesn't create the shortcut. I have tried so many different combinations of switches, quotes, and statements. I just can't seem to get it to work. I would very much appreciate any help with this, because I'm sure it is just something I have simply overlooked. Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you run each command directly (not in a batch file and without the `start`), does it work?

Comment: Copying to `"C:\users\public\desktop\"` folder requires elevation.

Comment: If you copy a link from somewhere it will still point to somewhere(else) and not to your newly installed software. You wil need to (re-)create the link with proper paramters. You'll need js-/vbscript/PowerShell/.inf or 3rd party apps to do this. [A quick look around will show you enaugh samples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=batch+create+shortcut)

Comment: The first line is not good. You assume the standard program files folder for 32-bit applications is always `C:\Program Files (x86)`. But this assumption might be wrong. The drive can be different and also the folder name can be different. 64-bit Windows defines the environment variable `ProgramFiles(x86)` with path to standard program files folder for 32-bit applications on 64-bit Windows. You should make use of it with `IF EXIST "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Yawcam\Yawcam.exe" GOTO :eof`.

Comment: It is also not good to define a label `eof` written in lower case as this might result in misleads on using in batch file also `goto :EOF`. `EOF` in upper case is a predefined label (with command extensions enabled as by default) for exiting batch execution. It would be better to replace in your batch file `eof` for example by `EndBatch`. Also use `EXIT` should be replaced by `EXIT /B` which is exactly the same as `goto :EOF`. `EXIT` without option `/B` always exits entire command process making it not possible to debug a batch file with starting it from within a command prompt window.

Comment: The `ELSE` on second line must be removed. Executing `if /?` in a command prompt window explains how to use an `IF ... ELSE` in correct syntax like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34118487/3074564) with more examples for correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The following rewrite requires to be run `As administrator`.

```bat
If Exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Yawcam\Yawcam.exe" GoTo :EOF

"\\hazel\software$\YawCam\v6.0\yawcam_install.exe" /SP- /VERYSILENT
XCopy "%~dp0Doc Cam.lnk" "%PUBLIC%\Desktop" /C /Y
Pause
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write it like this:

```cmd
pushd "\\hazel\software$" || exit /B 1
if not exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Yawcam\Yawcam.exe" (
    ".\YawCam\v6.0\yawcam_install.exe" /SP- /VERYSILENT
)
copy /Y ".\YawCam\Doc Cam.lnk" "%PUBLIC%\Desktop\Doc Cam.lnk"
popd
exit /B
```

What I did, and why:

- added [`pushd`](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) to resolve the UNC path `\\hazel\software$` as some commands might have trouble with such; `||` means to execute next command in case of failure, `exit /B 1` exits the batch file if `pushd` fails, like when the path could not be found; [`popd`](http://ss64.com/nt/popd.html) at the end restores the previous working directory finally;
- reversed the `if` query as you want something to happen in case the condition is *not* met; this also avoids the need of `goto`; in addition, *never* define a label `:EOF` as this is a reserved name (see this: [`goto`](http://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)); regard that your [`if`/`else`](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) syntax is wrong!
- used [environment variables](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) for system paths, like `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` and `%PUBLIC%`, because the directory locations may be different on some systems;
- removed the [`start`](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command as it is usually not necessary to run external (console) programs; (if it *is* required for this application for some reason, you might want to change the syntax to: `start "" /WAIT ".\YawCam\v6.0\yawcam_install.exe" /SP- /VERYSILENT`)
- replaced `xcopy` by [`copy`](http://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) since you are copying a single file only, in order not to having to deal with the `F = file, D = directory` prompt;
- added switch `/B` to [`exit`](http://ss64.com/nt/exit.html) in order to just terminate the batch file but not the hosting command prompt (`cmd`) instance;

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this method is necessarily the *best* way to go about it, but it got it working for our needs! I appreciate all your guys' help with this! We looked at each comment/answer and went from there. Thank you!

Here's what we did in the end:

```
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Yawcam\Yawcam.exe" GOTO eof

ELSE

start \\hazel\software$\YawCam\v6.0\yawcam_install.exe /SP- /VERYSILENT

:eof

Echo F|xcopy "\\hazel\software$\YawCam\Doc Cam.lnk" "C:\users\public\desktop\Doc Cam.lnk" /C /Y

EXIT
```

Hopefully this can help someone trying to do the same in the future!

Comment: This is still the wrong `if`/`else` syntax! Type `if /?` into a command prompt window and read the help text!